# doesn't display "Submission" table data in polymorpic relation laravel but if using dd () the data's appears

Tags: laravel

So, i just tried relation in laravel using polymorphic..

the data's appears when using dd(), but data not appears after i delete the "dd()"

#### Models

```
public function submission()
{
    return $this->morphTo('data');
}
```

#### with dd()

```
    $storage = ItemStorage::where('id', $barang_id)->first();

    $barang = $storage->submission;
    dd($barang);
```

#### result

```
Submission {#2218 ▼
#table: "barang"
#fillable: array:23 [▶]
#dates: array:3 [▶]
#attributes: array:23 [▶]
#original: array:23 [▶]
}
```

#### without dd()

```
public static function butuhdana($barang_id)
{
   $storage = ItemStorage::where('id', $barang_id)->first();

   $barang = $storage->submission;
}
```

#### result

```
Trying to get property 'submission' of non-object
```

Comment: could you add the whole function in with dd() part?

Comment: Try with optional method `optional($storage)->submission`

Answer (score 0):

i got the problem, it's not just one $barang_id, but more than that

#### Example

```
 $("#slide_nominal").ionRangeSlider({
          grid: true,
          min: {!! \App\Service\Modular\BarangHelper::butuhdana($barang->storage->id) >= 100000 ? 100000 : \App\Service\Modular\BarangHelper::butuhdana($barang->storage->id) !!},
          max: {!! \App\Service\Modular\BarangHelper::butuhdana($barang->storage->id)  !!},
          step: {!! \App\Service\Modular\BarangHelper::butuhdana($barang->storage->id) >= 100000 ? 50000 : \App\Service\Modular\BarangHelper::butuhdana($barang->storage->id) !!},
          prettify_enabled: true,
          prettify_separator: "."
});
```